# Relation between the eigendecomposition a PD matrix and its entry-wise positive counterpart

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, absolute-value, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

Suppose that we have a positive definite matrix $X$ and its entry-wise positive version $Y=|X|$ where $\forall i, j \;\; y_{ij}=|x_{ij}|$. Is there any relationship between their eigen-decompositions, more specifically their eigenvectors? If not, are there stronger constraints on $X$ that result in a relationship?